# azurerm_public_ips : expected attachment_status to be one of [Attached Unattached], got All

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

Terraform version : 1.3.1

AzureRm version 3.25.0

I have the following tf file.

```html
# this will list all IP addresses in a resource_group
data "azurerm_public_ips" "ip_addresses" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  attachment_status = "Unattached"
}

locals {
  inbound_ipv4  = [for ip in data.azurerm_public_ips.ip_addresses.public_ips: ip if ip.name == "ip-${var.cluster_name}-inbound"][0]
  outbound_ipv4 = [for ip in data.azurerm_public_ips.ip_addresses.public_ips: ip if ip.name == "ip-${var.cluster_name}-outbound"][0]
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  rg = azurerm_resource_group.rg
}
```

The first time I run this plan the outbound IP get allocated to a kubernetes cluster.
Due to an error somewhere else, the plan fails. I fix the error and restart the plan.
It now fails because there are no unattached ips.

```html
 on k8s-ip.tf line 10, in locals:
│   10:   outbound_ipv4 = [for ip in data.azurerm_public_ips.ip_addresses.public_ips: ip if ip.name == "ip-${var.cluster_name}-outbound"][0]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.azurerm_public_ips.ip_addresses.public_ips is list of object with 1 element
│     │ var.cluster_name is "k8s-lab-01"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the collection has no
│ elements.
```

I try to enter "All" as specified in the doc to avoid the crash above.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/Azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/public_ips

But the word "All" is not authorized.
I need the "All" keyword ( or a way to not crash here)

```html
Error: expected attachment_status to be one of [Attached Unattached], got All
│
│   with data.azurerm_public_ips.ip_addresses,
│   on k8s-ip.tf line 4, in data "azurerm_public_ips" "ip_addresses":
│    4:   attachment_status = "All"
│
```

My goal is to avoid the crash and be able to rerun the plan without failing here.
How can I proceed?

Comment: Can you add only the output of the `data.azurerm_public_ips.ip_addresses.public_ips` to the question? Because it's a list of objects, so you probably want to access a particular key. Of course, take care to obfuscate any sensitive information.

Comment: the resource group contains 2 public ip addresses.
ip-k8s-lab-01-inbound is unassigned and ip-k8s-lab-01-outbound is assigned.
In the above tf file, I cannot get the list of public ip addresses, I can only get the list of assigned or the list of unassigned.
Since I have 1 assigned and 1 unassigned (and 2 unassigned at first execution), my bloc always fail.
One of the [for ...] is systematically null.

Comment: In fact I want to return the ip named inbound and the ip named outbound, and use them somewhere else in the creation of the k8s cluster. It has to be reentrant. Because if terraform apply fail I endup with existing ip addresses that have to be reused for completing the plan

Comment: Sure, but can you just temporarily add the output to show what the data source will have? So I can answer your question. :)

Comment: I fixed it by referencing the resource instead of looking up existing resources in the resource group
  inbound_ipv4  = azurerm_public_ip.clustername_ip_in


  outbound_ipv4 = azurerm_public_ip.clustername_ip_out

Comment: Hi @CloudAnywhere if the solution provided was helpful, please incorporate it as an answer to help the SO community.

Comment: No, no answer provided. This is a bug in the documentation and potentially in the new AzureRm module. The "All" keyword is usefull and needed. Doc mentions it but module does not accept it.